# Haskell - Accepting different types and acting accordingly

Tags: haskell

Lets say I got the following very basic example:

```
f :: Either Int String -> IO ()
```

as well as a function `g :: Int -> IO ()` and a function `g' :: String -> IO ()` and I basically want to implement `f` as a "selector" which calls `g` or `g'` depending on its input, so that in the future I only have to work with `f` because I know that my program will only encounter either Int or String.

Does this way of using `Either` make sense? The convention seems to be to use it mainly for Error and Exception handling.

If it does make sense, what would be a good way or best practice to implement such an example? I've heard/read about `case` as well as bifunctors.

If it does not: what is the haskell way of handling the possibility of different input types? Or is this something which should be avoided from the beginning?

Comment: What do `g` and `g'` do? Depending on what you're trying to achieve, this may or may not be a sensible idea.

Comment: Yes, this function already exists as `either`.

Comment: You just discovered how to eliminate a value in a sum type (`Either`). Nice! This is a fundamental operation in functional programming. As you saw, you indeed need two functions for that, one for each possible constructor (`Left/Right`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So that definitely can make sense and one way to implement that is:

```
f :: Either Int String -> IO ()
f e =
    case e of
        Left l -> g l
        Right r -> g' r
```

or using [`either`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Either.html#v:either):

```
import Data.Either (either)
f :: Either Int String -> IO ()
f = either g g'
```

Note that in the second version I don't assign a variable name to the `Either Int String` argument. That is called [eta conversion / eta reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion). But obviously you could also write `f e = either g g' e`.

Answer (score 5):

As an armchair Haskell programmer, it seems fine to me.

```
f :: Either Int String -> IO ()
f (Left n) = g n
f (Right s) = g' s
```